# Implement Minimax Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, f#, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I have already scoured the web for psuedocode, working examples, stack overflow problems/solutions of the same realm, and I have not found anything to be of help so far so I'm reaching out on here.

I'm trying to implement the Minimax algorithm in my Tic Tac Toe game in a very basic way (no alpha/beta pruning). Let me explain each helper method I have, and then I can share parts of my actual code if you need it. ***Note*** (I am NOT using depth when checking for terminal state, only checking for win or checking for a draw.)

First, I have the utility MakeBestMove that will be called upon a computer move, then within MakeBestMove will call MiniMax, which then will call itself until the boardState reaches a terminal state or when there are no moves left.

I want MakeBestMove to return the best move, and my MiniMax function to return a score of the boardState.

If you are familiar with MiniMax, when state is terminal the state is scored. I've used -100 for player O win, 100 for player X win, and 0 for draw to score my game. This is done in my EvaluateScore helper function.I also have a function that will determine the available moves based upon current state of the game board to help me iterate through the open moves. Also, it might be important to note that player "X" is always a human and player "O" is always the computer.

I'm trying to use the same approach I used in Python to implement MiniMax with F#, and it should theoretically work, even though it's not being loyal to F# functional paradigm.

For some reason or another, it does not behave how I would expect it to. I have spent hours going over each line of code to make sure I wasn't having any weird side-effects, but have not had any success. I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. I know I wrote it very imperatively, but I do think it can work this way, but can't seem to figure out why it doesn't and what I might possibly be missing. Any help is greatly appreciated!

CODE BEHAVIOR ISSUES: 
 1. Does not return bestMove in MakeBestMove correctly
 2. While the Minimax function appears to look like it is behaving correctly by recursively iterating through different terminal boardStates, the MakeBestMove will not block moves for "O" but will take the winning move when it's one move away.

HOW I WANT MY CODE TO BEHAVE: 
1. Ability to correctly score boardState (which I believe I already am doing.)
2. Ability to return that score if boardState is terminal, or if there are no more moves left to take (which I'm doing)
3. Ability to use that score to then make the best move choice (this is the issue)

**EDIT** I wanted to add a 'walk through' of the calls being made within my program, in case you wanted to run my code through Visual Studio and test it out.

In Program.fs is where my code starts, and when it calls `ComputerPlayerTurn()` then it will use Game.fs, where `ComputerPlayerTurn()` is called then will initialize the variable `let mutable computerMove` to = `MakeBestMove(board)`. After `MakeBestMove(board)` is called, within the function is where `MiniMax(board) marker` is called.

The following code is where the behavior issues I'm having are found:

```
let rec MiniMax(board) marker = 
    let mutable bestValue = 0
    let mutable board = board
    let mutable moves = GetListOfMoves(board) 
    if GameWon(board) marker = true || GetListOfMoves(board).Count = 0 then
        bestValue <- EvaluateScore(board)
    else
        if marker = "X" then
            bestValue <- -100
            for move in moves do  
                board <- ModifyBoard(board) move marker
                bestValue <- max(MiniMax(board) "O")(bestValue) 
                board <- ModifyBoard(board) move " "
            bestValue <- bestValue
        else 
            bestValue <- 100
            for move in moves do  
                board <- ModifyBoard(board) move marker
                bestValue <- min(MiniMax(board) "X")(bestValue) 
                board <- ModifyBoard(board) move " "
            bestValue <- bestValue
    bestValue

let MakeBestMove (board) marker = 
    let mutable board = board
    let mutable bestMove = 0
    let mutable bestValue = 0
    let mutable bestMoves = ResizeArray<int>()
    let moves = GetListOfMoves(board)
    for move in moves do
        board <- ModifyBoard(board) move marker
        bestValue <- MiniMax(board) "X" 
        board <- ModifyBoard(board) move " "
        if marker = "X" then
            if bestValue = 100 then
                bestMove <- move
            if bestValue > 0 then
                bestMoves.Add(move)
            else if bestValue = 0 then
                bestMoves.Add(move)
        elif marker = "O" then
            if bestValue = -100 then
                bestMove <- move
            if bestValue < 0 then
                bestMoves.Add(move)
            else if bestValue = 0 then
                bestMoves.Add(move)
    if bestMove = 0 && bestMoves.Count > 0 then
        bestMove <- bestMoves.[0]
    elif bestMove <> 0 then
        bestMove <- bestMove
    else
        bestMove <- GetListOfMoves(board).[0]
    bestMove
```

My code is on Github on my MASTER branch of my repository:  https://github.com/sinnmk/fsharp-tictactoe

Comment: when you put `let mutable board = board` are you expecting the input board to change upon exciting the function? Because that local copy of `board` is mutable but the one calling is immutable. In other words, changes to `board` inside the function wont affect the calling `board`.

Comment: To format your code, there's no need to use the \` markers around every line. Paste your code into the edit box, then highlight it and click the `{}` button; this will indent the entire code block by four spaces, making it appear as a code block. As a bonus, this will preserve indentation — in an F# question, that's vital so that the code is readable. :-)

Comment: Thanks rmun! I'm new to posting questions on Stack Overflow, so this was helpful information :)

Comment: Hi AMieres, If I understand what you are asking correctly, the board that is passed into the `MiniMax` function when called is immutable like you said. What I thought I am doing by declaring `let mutable board = board` is that I can change the mutable variable `board` within my function, but would not modify the `board` of the ACTUAL game. So basically, I want to make a copy or clone of `board` to be able to run `Minimax` and `MakeBestMove` with the mutable copy of the `board`. Correct me if I'm wrong or if I misunderstood you. Thanks for your question!

Comment: @mksinn, another handy tip is to scroll down and look below the edit box as you type. There's a live preview of what you're typing, so that you can see whether your Markdown is producing the formatting you want. But most people never realize that they can scroll down further, so they don't realize the live preview is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if ((GameWon(board) marker) = true || (moves.Count = 0)) then
```

It is only considering ties and games where `marker` wins.
It should also consider games where `marker` loses:

```
if GameWon board "O" || GameWon board "X" || moves.Count = 0 then
```

I removed unnecessary parenthesis and conditions like `= true`.